# Optimizing Cache Size Based on Device Memory in a React-native Application

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on a React application and wanted to dynamically adjust the behavior based on the available memory of a user's device.

I have been getting crashes when fetching data using react-query, useInfiniteQuery hook to be more specific. And after some tests I noticed it happens on low memory devices.

My goal is to utilize cache more effectively by considering the device's memory capacity. From my research, it seems there isn't a direct way to achieve this in React or JavaScript since they are designed to be platform-independent.

Here's the code where the crash is originating from:

```
 // Use the useInfiniteQuery from react query to allow easy pagination management
  const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    isSuccess,
    isError,
    error,
    fetchNextPage,
    hasNextPage,
    isFetching,
    isFetchingNextPage,
  } = useInfiniteQuery<Loop54ProductsResponse, AxiosError>({
    queryKey: [
      "paginated-products",
      query ? query : "",
      storeId,
      sortBy,
      filterByOption,
    ],
    enabled: query !== "" && !!storeId,
    queryFn: ({ pageParam = 0 }) =>
      getPaginatedProductsWithFilters({
        storeId: storeId || 0,
        loop54Endpoint,
        pageParam,
        productsPerPage,
        sortByOption:
          sortBy !== "MOST_POPULAR" && sortBy !== "COMPARISON_PRICE"
            ? sortByOption
            : undefined,
        filterByOption: filterByOption.length > 0 ? filterByOption : undefined,
        query,
      }),
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => {
      const maxPages = lastPage.results
        ? lastPage.results.count / productsPerPage
        : 0;
      const nextPage = pages.length;
      return nextPage <= maxPages ? nextPage : undefined;
    },
    
  });
```

Question:

Has anyone implemented a similar caching strategy based on device memory? If so, how did you approach it, and were there any noticeable benefits or pitfalls?